# Why am I getting an error when using "ng add"

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, node-modules, init

First time using Angular. I am trying to use theming but I am unable to. I think it stems from getting an error message when doing "ng add @angular/material". Since I got an error message, I just did "npm install @angular/material" and it ran. However, I was never able to set a theme. Here is the error message[Error message from "ng add @angular/material"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5uAk.png)

I tried going into my files and looking at where the file is missing but I don't really know where to start. I've also tried googling it and haven't gotten anywhere.

Anyone know what the issue is here? Anyone run into this error before? Any advice on what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.